# Finding fork() for UNIX Pipe on a Windows 10 Computer

Tags: c++, unix, fork

I have an assignment to create a UNIX pipe to copy a given program from one end to the other. I am using a Windows 10 computer with visual studio. The assignment must be written in C++. The textbook describes a way to do this using the fork() command and wait() commands. However, these don't show up as available functions. They seem to be contained in unistd.h and sys/wait.h but I cannot find these headers.
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: A quick start may be using lab servers provided by your school. If you want to work on your local machine, try vmware/virtual box + ubuntu/any other linux system + vscode + g++/clang++

Comment: Does it have to be a _Unix_ pipe?  Windows has its own [pipe implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/pipes).

Answer (score 2):

You've been given a task to write a program using the POSIX operating system API. Windows 10 is not a POSIX operating system.

You should compile the program on a POSIX system that does have the headers unistd.h sys/wait.h. I recommend using Linux for this task. You can run it in a virtual machine inside the windows system if that is convenient for you.

Cross-compilation is a thing that exists, but setting up a build chain for it can be a challenge and I don't know if one exists for Windows to Linux or other POSIX systems.

Comment: Thanks! My issue was that I need to compile with Cygwin, rather than using debugger in Visual Studio.